# Using async.js map with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I'm reading the metadata of a number of audio files using node. The order of the resulting data varies since the metadata is read asynchronously, and I need the metadata in the same order as the files.

To solve this I'm trying to use the *async.js* (https://github.com/caolan/async) map function, and for the metadata *musicmetadata* (https://github.com/leetreveil/musicmetadata) (which is the only library I've found which supports all the different audio tags).

However, I'm struggling to get these two libraries to work in tandem. Which I believe has something to do with the fact that *musicmetadata* sends the resulting data using an EventTransmitter, but most likely I'm not using the functions properly.

Below are my code snippets:

```
var async = require("async");

files = ["file1.mp3", "file.m4a", "file3.ogg"];
async.map(files, readMetadata, function (err, res) {
    // this is never called
});
```

The function to read the metadata:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var mm = require('musicmetadata');

function readMetadata(file, callback) {
    var parser = mm(fs.createReadStream(file), {
        duration: true
    });
    parser.on("metadata", function (metadata) {
        var data = {
            artist: metadata.artist[0],
            album: metadata.album,
            title: metadata.title,
            duration: metadata.duration
        };
        callback(null, data);
    });
}
```

Ex:
Say I want to read the metadata of the files:

```
files = ["song1", "song2", "song3"];
```

Then I want the resulting array to look something like this:

```
[{
    artist: "artist1",
    album: "album1",
    title: "title",
    duration: duration
},
 {
    artist: "artist2",
    album: "album2",
    title: "title2",
    duration: duration2
},
 {
    artist: "artist3",
    album: "album3",
    title: "title3",
    duration: duration3
}];
```

Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: "I need the metadata in the same order as the files."  Why?

Comment: Because if I add an entire folder of audio files I want the array to reflect the folder structure. Otherwise if I say add a folder of an album the songs won't appear in order.

Comment: Well, your directory listing order is non-deterministic depending on the filesystem, and should not be relied upon.  But if you want to match the files array order with the resulting metadata array order, that sort of makes sense.  However, there is absolutely no reason at all why you need to process these files in-order.  You have the array index of the file.  Just set the array index of the metadata to be the same.  If item `3` comes before item `1`, it doesn't matter as long as you set the index.  If it were me, I would keep the filename with the metadata anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling map method with "paths" as a variable but you created:

`files = ["file1.mp3", "file.m4a", "file3.ogg"];`

Shouldn't be this way?

```
async.map(files, readMetadata, function (err, res) {
    // this is never called
});
```

Comment: That was just a typo. It's 'paths' in the real code. Sorry.